# sqlite drops or rounds decimal on restart

Tags: android, cordova, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a Cordova app with the sqlite plugin.
In one view I save some data to a table which includes a field which is defined as a decimal(10,5), but could hold either an integer or a float. Once the data is saved to the database, it goes to a view which queries the database and re-presents the entered data to the user.

If I enter say, 2.8, the data gets re-presented to me as 2.8. So far. so good. But if I kill the app, then restart it and move to the view which presents the data, it shows 3 instead of 2.8.

If I save 0.5, it shows 0 after restart, and 5.5 changes to 6. I am not formatting the data either on saving to the database, nor on subsequently selecting from it and I am saving the data as 0.5 as opposed to "0.5".

This is happening on both the Android and iOS versions of the app.

I have even rebuilt the database with the field as Text, and the same thing happens.